# How can I create a reloading animation for a shotgun?

Tags: animation

I am making a game and I want to create a shotgun animation, in the animation the player will push the bullets to the gun but my problem is that in games the player need to push number of bullets that is equal the number of bullets missing so how can I create this? Do I need to create animation for all the number of bullets that are missing(create animation that he push one and than creating an animaion he push two and so on..) or there is an option for creating one animation and use some feture that I dont know is exist?

Comment: No, you create one animation where he loads one bullet. The number of bullets has to be done in the game engine with game logic. Unless you want loading one bullet to look different from loading more bullets, then you have to use different animations.

Comment: So if I want him the pull up the gun on the first shell loaded and on the last one to pull down I need to create three? one for the first one for the last and one for the bullets between?
okey thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know how game designers usually do this... you want to create a game ;) I would say make one animation for pulling up the gun, one for loading the shell and one for putting the gun down. So then you also have animations for pulling up the gun and putting down the gun even if you don't load a shell.